# Reading from a text file and sorting

Tags: f#

I have managed to read my text file which contains line by line random numbers. When I output lines using `printfn "%A" lines` I get `seq ["45"; "5435" "34"; ... ]` so I assume that lines must be a datatype list.

```
open System
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);;
let lines = readLines @"C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\unsorted.txt"
```

I am now trying to sort the list by lowest to highest but it does not have the `.sortBy()` method. Any chance anyone can tell me how to manually do this? I have tried turning it to an array to sort it but it doesn't work.

```
let array = [||]
let counter = 0
for i in lines do
 array.[counter] = i
 counter +1
Console.ReadKey <| ignore
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a seq, not a list. Try [`Seq.sortBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.sortby%5B't,'key%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: so, would it look something like `let sorted = lines.Seq.sortBy` ? @rmunn

Comment: No. `Seq.sortBy` is a function, not a method. It would be `let sorted = Seq.sortBy int lines`, or `let sorted = lines |> Seq.sortBy int`.

Comment: could I then loop through the `sorted` using `for i in sorted` ? I appreciated this and will look into Sequences @rmunn

Comment: @KDOT to use a fluent interface you'd need to nuget Fsharp.Fluent. It would look like `Seq.sort lines` or `Seq.sortDescendings lines`.

Comment: One thing to realize is that sequences are *lazy*, and will only produce their contents once their contents are required. And then you'll only be able to get the seq's contents once, otherwise you'll get "Error: Cannot read from a closed TextReader." If you're coming from a C# background, then just remember that an F# sequence is exactly the same as an `IEnumerable` in C#, and you'll mostly get things right.

Comment: Note that *other* sequences would be perfectly fine with producing their values repeatedly. It's just the sequence (`IEnumerable`) that you get from `System.IO.File.ReadLines` that you won't be able to repeat. If you need to run through its values repeatedly, store it in a list or array via `let storedLines = lines |> List.ofSeq` (or else `lines |> Array.ofSeq`). Whether you want a list or an array will depend: do you want a singly-linked list (the F# `list` type is a linked list), with O(1) head access and appending but O(N) random access, or an array with O(1) random access but slow appends?

Comment: Probably it's more idiomatic to write `Console.ReadLine() |> ignore` at the very end. If you leave off the () it will be a partially applied function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the lines are integers, you can just use `Seq.sortBy int`, like so:

```
open System
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)
let lines = readLines @"C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\unsorted.txt"
let sorted = lines |> Seq.sortBy int
```

If some of the lines may not be valid integers, then you'd need to run through a parsing and validation step. E.g.:

```
let tryParseInt s =
    match System.Int32.TryParse s with
    | true, n -> Some n
    | false, _ -> None
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)
let lines = readLines @"C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\unsorted.txt"
let sorted = lines |> Seq.choose tryParseInt |> Seq.sort
```

Note that the `tryParseInt` function I just wrote is returning the int value, so I used `Seq.sort` instead of `Seq.sortBy int`, and the output of that function chain is going to be a sequence of ints rather than a sequence of strings. If you really wanted a sequence of strings, but only the strings that could be parsed to ints, you could have done it like this:

```
let tryParseInt s =
    match System.Int32.TryParse s with
    | true, _ -> Some s
    | false, _ -> None
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)
let lines = readLines @"C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\unsorted.txt"
let sorted = lines |> Seq.choose tryParseInt |> Seq.sortBy int
```

Note how I'm returning `s` from this version of `tryParseInt`, so that `Seq.choose` is keeping the strings (but throwing away any strings that failed to validate through `System.Int32.TryParse`). There's plenty more possibilities, but that should give you enough to get started.

Comment: [`Seq.choose` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.choose%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: As much as I love the detail, `let sorted = Seq.sortBy int lines` worked fine :) +1 for the information however, also I just did a `for x in sorted` and outputted each number :)

Answer (score 1):

All the comments are valid but I'm a bit more concerned about your very imperative loop.

So here's an example:

To read all the lines:

```
open System.IO

let file = @"c:\tmp\sort.csv"
let lines = File.ReadAllLines(file)
```

To sort the lines: 
`let sorted = Seq.sort lines`

`sorted  |> Seq.length // to get the number of lines`
`sorted |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Length) // to iterate over all lines and get the length of each line`

You can also use a list comprehension syntax:
`[for l in sorted -> l.ToUpper()]`

`Seq` will work for all kinds of collections but you can replace it with Array (mutable) or List (F# List).